# Django+ajax (jquery): http error code 403 (forbidden)

Tags: ajax, django

I was developing a simple ajax call ($.ajax function with type, url and data as options parameters) with jquery in a page, but i got 403 error.
So i have added to $.ajax function a further options parameter for csrf, and the corresponding token is correcly displayed in the template.
But i got 403 error again.
I also have tried to add to view handler (in views.py) a csrf decorator, like `@csrf_protect` or `@requires_csrf_token` but nothing is changed.

Some help?

I have seen this pattern to make an ajax call in django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#s-ajax

but it is really too much code for me to make a simple ajax call, so i find a short solution

Comment: The docs are there for a reason. You're getting a 403 because the CSRF token isn't be passed. Follow what the docs say to do and you'll be fine.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know how to accept. Now i see the button to accept. It isn't intuitive at all for me, if there would be a mouse hover event handler that color the button when the mouse hovers i think that the user experience would be better.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use the CSRF protection for that view, the decorator you want is `@csrf_exempt`--those other will just ensure that the CSRF protection *is* applied.  That's probably the simplest solution, especially if the call isn't particularly security-sensitive.

Alternatively, make sure you're following the method mentioned in the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#page-uses-ajax-without-any-html-form

Comment: The secret is to add this to the top of your views.py: `from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie`
<br>
`@ensure_csrf_cookie`